# In CSV one column I want to have a URL link and also some text

Tags: bash, csv, hyperlink

Currently I am writing one shell script which creates a CSV file with 3 columns. The first two columns have string data while the 3rd one will contain a hyperlink also some text.

[Link_data][1] some text

when no test is there links are getting created successfully but when some text message is there link is failed to create.

Need some help here.This is my code

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Function to retrieve commits for a repository between two dates
get_commits() {
    #local repo_url="2024-02-15"
    local start_date="2024-02-15"
    local end_date="2024-02-25"

    # Clone the repository to a temporary directory
    local tmp_dir=$(mktemp -d)
    git clone "$repo_url" "$tmp_dir" &> /dev/null || { echo "Error: Failed to clone repository $repo_url"; return 1; }

    # Navigate to the repository directory
    cd "$tmp_dir" || { echo "Error: Failed to navigate to repository directory"; return 1; }

    # Retrieve commits between start and end dates
    git log --pretty=format:"$start_date;%h;%an;%s" --date=short --after="$start_date" --before="$end_date"

    # Cleanup temporary directory
    rm -rf "$tmp_dir"
}

# Function to create Jira links
create_jira_link() {
    local commit_message=`echo $1 | tr ',' ' '`
    local jira_pattern="([A-Z]+-[0-9]+)"
    echo "$commit_message" | sed -E "s/${jira_pattern}/\=hyperlink(\"\"https:\/\/comapnyname.atlassian.net\/browse\/\1\"\",\"\"\1\"\")"/g
}

# Read repository component names from the text file
repo_list_file="repolist.txt"
if [ ! -f "$repo_list_file" ]; then
    echo "Error: Repository list file $repo_list_file not found"
    exit 1
fi

# Validate command line arguments
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <start_date> <end_date>"
    exit 1
fi

# Start and end dates for filtering commits
start_date="$1"
end_date="$2"

# Output CSV file path
csv_output_file="output.csv"

# Generate CSV report header
echo "Component,Date,Commit ID,Author,Commit Message" > "$csv_output_file"

# Iterate over each repository component name
while IFS= read -r component; do
    repo_url="git@bitbucket.org:companyname/$component.git"
    commits=$(get_commits "$repo_url" "$start_date" "$end_date")
    echo $commits
    if [ -n "$commits" ]; then
        # Store the first commit author and message to be used if there are multiple commits for the same component
        IFS=';' read -r first_date first_commit_id first_author first_message <<< "$commits"
        # Create Jira links in commit message
        first_commit_info_with_links=$(create_jira_link "$first_message")
        # Append the first commit to the CSV file with the component name
        echo "\"$component\",\"$first_date\",\"$first_commit_id\",\"$first_author\",\"$first_commit_info_with_links\"" >> "$csv_output_file"
        # If there are more commits, append only the subsequent commits without the component name
        tail -n +2 <<< "$commits" | while IFS=';' read -r date commit_id author message; do
            # Create Jira links in commit message
            commit_info_with_links=$(create_jira_link "$message")
            echo ",\"$date\",\"$commit_id\",\"$author\",\"$commit_info_with_links\"" >> "$csv_output_file"
        done
    else
        echo "No commits found between $start_date and $end_date for $component"
    fi
done < "$repo_list_file"

echo "CSV report generated successfully: $csv_output_file"
```

Comment: It's a little difficult to follow your (long) bash script without knowing what data you have (input), what you expect, and what errors you see (exact output). Could you post some examples ? (just use dummy data).